# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] jquery 3.2.1 and angular 1.6.6

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui

I started the first app with angularJs and Kendo UI, then I had an error in the console that says:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.6/$injector/modulerr
>       at angular.min.js:7
>       at angular.min.js:43
>       at p (angular.min.js:8)
>       at g (angular.min.js:42)
>       at hb (angular.min.js:46)
>       at c (angular.min.js:22)
>       at Uc (angular.min.js:22)
>       at we (angular.min.js:21)
>       at HTMLDocument. (angular.min.js:334)
>       at j (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="css/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="css/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="css/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

</head>
<body ng-app="myApp"  ng-controller="home">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <p>{{ today | date }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li><a href="#!/">Dash Board</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#!/addEmp">Add Employee</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dummy Link</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div ng-view class="col-lg-10">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-route.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-resource.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/kendo.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
```

app.js

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute", 'ngResource', "ui.bootstrap", "kendo.directives"]);
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
            .when("/", {
                templateUrl: "home.html",
                controller: "home"
            })
            .when("/addEmp", {
                templateUrl: "addEmp.html",
                controller: "addEmp"
            });
});

app.controller("home", function ($scope) {
    $scope.today = new Date();
});
```

Comment: juste for the record, It's often not a good idea to mix angular and jquery.
Try to remove 'ngResource', "ui.bootstrap", "kendo.directives", then add them back one by one.

 It should isolate the bad module.

Comment: @sab "ui.bootstrap", "kendo.directives" must be put. but 'ngResource' is not effect but when i searched this was the solution, but not working with me.

Comment: please make jsfiddle snippet for your problem that will help you get answer more quickly

Comment: I know, but I just try to isolate the error.

Comment: @artgb Ok, but How please?